# rospy.Time.now() returns 0

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
rospy.init_node('h')
print(rospy.Time.now()) => 0
```

**Prints zero? Here is the context**

1. Kinetic
2. rosparam get /use_sim_time -> true

   $ rostopic info /clock
   Type: rosgraph_msgs/Clock

   Publishers:

   - /gazebo (http://10.0.0.95:36787/)

   Subscribers:

   - /rosout (http://10.0.0.95:45435/)
   - /gazebo (http://10.0.0.95:36787/)
   - /gazebo_gui (http://10.0.0.95:43597/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300956/rospy.time.now()-returns-0/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-08-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-19**:
Is Gazebo paused?

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-19**:
No, it’s up. Also when I rostopic echo /clock I
see the messages go by. Also when I set /use_sim_time to
False the same code works.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-21**:
Anyone? I am stumped. Thinking that I had corrupted something in my install, i see the same behavior on a different computer altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know you've already reinstalled -- but in case someone else (or even you) runs into this later -- it is possible you simply have a race condition. If you put the print() statement in a loop, I imagine your values would start to increase. It is possible that either the python node came up and printed before gazebo really started publishing /clock, or that the print statement happened before the first clock message came in.

I've seen some codebases where the developers explicitly wait until time > 0 before letting the rest of the initialization proceed.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-24**:
Interesting information... In my case I just extracted that code sample to show the problem starkly but it was actually in a loop and I did wait a while. I also did see some kind of weird behavior as I toggled /use_simtime and watched what happened.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-28**:
It appears `rospy.sleep(0.0)` works (at least in noetic), at least a single clock message has to arrive to return from that sleep.